# Умножение всех значений в столбце на число

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо умножить все значения в столбце, например на 10. Как это можно сделать?

Дан столбец со значениями:

```
Col 1
1
2
3
4
5
...
2152
```

Необходимый результат:

```
Col 1
10
20
30
40
50
...
21520
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET Col = Col * 10;
```

Comment: Есть одна проблема - при включённом safe_update сервер откажется выполнить такой запрос...

Comment: Запрос выполнился успешно. Необходимый результат был достигнут. Спасибо за дополнение! Если что, буду знать